# Trying to build map from CSV data. Just getting blank map witrh no data points

Tags: r, maps, leaflet, geocoding

Here is a small script that I put together.

```
MyData <- read.csv(file="http://www.grex.org/~ev/breweries.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")

library(DT)
datatable(MyData[,c("name","address1","address2","city","state","code","country")])


library(leaflet)
map <- 
    MyData %>% 
    leaflet() %>% 
    addTiles() %>% 
    addCircles(~name, ~address1, ~address2, ~city, ~state, ~country, radius = 200, color="blue", opacity = 0.8)
map
```

The data is downloaded and appears to be fine.

[image]

However, nothing is showing up on my map.

[image]

I'm trying to follow the example from the link below.  It seems super-simple, yet I seem to be missing something critical.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2016/03/22/introducing-r-tools-for-visual-studio-3/

Does anyone here have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`addCircles` needs latitude and longitude coordinates for each brewery to plot the points on a map. In this case, you can get them from the `breweries_geocode` data set (from the same web page where you downloaded the breweries data) and merge them into `MyData`:

```
MyData2 <- read.csv(file="http://www.grex.org/~ev/breweries_geocode.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")

map <- 
  MyData %>% 
  left_join(MyData2, by=c("id")) %>%
  leaflet() %>% 
  addTiles() %>% 
  addCircles(~longitude, ~latitude, popup=~name, radius = 200, color="blue", opacity = 0.8)

map
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  Works great!!  There must also be a way to do using address1 and addrss2, right.  I did some research about how to obtain longitude and latitude from an address without using Google's API.  I tried several libraries but couldn't get anything working.  Is there a way toy do this with some R package and address1 + address2, like you see in the original link that I posted?

Comment: I haven't tried to get lat/lon from addresses, but I'm sure there's a way. In the link you posted, the data they're using already includes lat and lon, so they didn't need to get lat and lon from addresses.